# Counting total monthly values from a CSV in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to record monthy sales totals over the course of 2.5 years in a csv data set.

I started with a csv file of transaction history for a SKU, which was sorted by date (MM/DD/YYYY), with varying statuses indicating whether the item was sold, archived (quoted, not sold), or open. I managed to figure out how to only display the "sold" rows, but cannot figure out how to display a total amount sold per month.
Here's what I have thus far.

```
#Import Libraries
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import pandas as pd

#Set Variables
fields = ['Date', 'Qty', 'Status']
file = r'kp4.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file, usecols=fields)

# Filters Dataset to only display "Sold" items in Status column 
data = (df[df['Status'] == "Sold"])

print (data)
```

Output:

```
             Date Qty Status
4     2/21/2018    5   Sold
4     2/21/2018    5   Sold
11    2/16/2018   34   Sold
14    3/16/2018    1   Sold
```

My ideal output would look something like this:

```
         Date   Qty  Status
4     02/2018    39    Sold
5     03/2018     1    Sold
```

I've tried groupy, manipulating the year format, assigning indexes per other tutorials and have gotten nothing but errors. If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the code for what you've tried already; it sounds like you are on the right track and we won't simply write code for you and pointing you in the "right direction" is a bit broad but (especially since you're getting errors and not incorrect output) it sounds like we could help you debug and fix what you've tried already. It definitely sounds to me like you're on the right track though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df=df.drop_duplicates()

df.groupby(df.Date.dt.strftime('%m/%Y')).agg({'Qty':'sum','Status':'first'})
Out[157]: 
         Qty Status
Date               
02/2018   39   Sold
03/2018    1   Sold
```

Comment: @KStofz yw happy coding